# $p$-adic valuations of infinite products

Tags: real-analysis, analytic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory

There are several ways to argue that the $q$-adic valuation on $\mathbb Q$ can be extended to a valuation $\mathsf v_q$ on the field $\mathbb R$ of real numbers.

I know that such a valuation cannot be explicitely given. Nevertheless I suspect that it is possible to compute very special values.

I summarize two questions here, because they are related. Denote by $\mathbb P$ the set of prime numbers.

1. Let $(a_p)_{p \in \mathbb P}$ be a sequence of rational numbers such that $\prod_{p \in \mathbb P} a_p$ is convergent (wrt euclidean topology). Let $q \in \mathbb P$ and assume that $\sum_{p \in \mathbb P} \mathsf v_q(a_p)$ is also convergent. Does it follow that $\mathsf v_q(\prod_{p \in \mathbb P} a_p) = \sum_{p \in \mathbb P} \mathsf v_q(a_p)$?

An obvious proof attempt is to show that $\mathsf v_q(\prod_{p >n} a_p)$ tends to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity. This would of course be easy if $\mathsf v_p$ would be continuous with respect to the euclidean topology.

2. The understanding of 1. could lead to constructions of real numbers with prescribed $q$-adic valuations. For instance, does there exists $x \in \mathbb R$ such that $\mathsf v_q(x) = 1$ for all $q \in \mathbb P$?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: For $a_n\in \Bbb{Q}^*$ then $\prod_{n\ge 1} a_n$ converges in $\Bbb{Q}_p^*$ iff $\lim_{n\to \infty} v_p(a_n-1)= \infty$. If it converges then yes $v_p(\prod_{n\ge 1} a_n) = \sum_{n\ge 1} v_p(a_n)$ (only finitely many terms are non-zero). I mean $p$ prime and $v_p(p^k u/v) = k$ if $p\nmid uv$.

Comment: Thank you! But now the convergence depends on $p$ which I would like to avoid.

Comment: I don't understand "Assume that $\sum_{p \in \mathbb P} \mathsf v_q(a_p)$ is also convergent". For some given $q$? Or for all $q$? And does it matter at all that your index set for the sequence is supposed to be the primes, as opposed to just, say, natural numbers?

Comment: I edited the question. Sorry for the typos. Of course, it does not make a difference which countable index set you choose. But in view of using 1. for 2., it makes sense to use the primes. You can leave your -1, I am not out for upvotes but for math.

Comment: Thanks for editing, I've removed my down vote (I'm all for math and good questions too). I think then question 1 is answered in the negative by reuns such that question 2 seems a bit pointless. I also still don't understand how using the primes as index set is supposed to be helpful there.

Answer (score 2):

For a sequence $(a_n)\in \Bbb{Q}$ then $\prod_{n\ge 1} a_n$ is the limit of a sequence, namely $(\prod_{n\le N} a_n)_{N\ge 1}$, and the limit if it exists (often it doesn't) is not the same at all in $\Bbb{R}$ and in $\Bbb{Q}_p$. The convergence of one is not related to the other, you can have that $\prod_{n\ge 1} a_n$  converges to $1$ in $\Bbb{R}$ and to $p$ in $\Bbb{Q}_p$.

If $\prod_{n\ge 1} a_n$ converges to $b$ in $\Bbb{Q}_p$ then $v_p(b)=\sum_{n\ge 1} v_p(a_n)$.

So if  $\prod_{n\ge 1} a_n$  converges to $1$ in $\Bbb{R}$ and to $p$ in $\Bbb{Q}_p$ then $v_p(1)=0$ is not related to $\sum_{n\ge 1} v_p(a_n)=v_p(b)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{p}(v_{q}(a_{p}))$ is given to be convergent. Now, as the discrete valuation takes discrete values, preferably maybe from $Z$, the above series is convergent $\iff$ it is eventually zero. Which means question 1 boils down to finite case for the same problem, to which the answer is yes.
Which I believe leads to a vacuous answer for question $2$.